# How to drag an image to the side panel to open with Chrome

Tags: 11.04, launcher

When i drag an image (In this case an png) all elements in the Panel go gray except for Firefox. This means that i can open and show the png image with Firefox but i also have Chrome in that list. How can i make it so Chrome also appears with color (Not grayed)

Image of problem:

Only Firefox appears highlighted instead of Firefox and Chrome

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Chromium does not announce that it can open .png files in its .desktop file but Firefox does. Compare the MimeType lines in /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop and /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop.

Please report this bug by running `ubuntu-bug chromium-browser`